# Spring Data: Hibernate update query

Tags: spring-data

How to increase current column value by given amount?
Following query sets value stored in'balance' variable:

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update BankAccount b set b.balance = (b.balance + :depositAmount) where b.id = :id")
    void updateBalance(@Param("depositAmount") double depositAmount, @Param("id") String id);
```

I expect that above method adds depositAmount to current balance. It is not like that: depositAmount is being set as a current balance.

Comment: What is your question?